# ArrayToDataTable not accepting datetime type

Tags: google-visualization

I have this code here for filtering my areachart by date, but it's not working correctly because `arrayToDataTable` is not accepting `dateTime` type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Anyone know how to fix this?

This is my script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["controls", "corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GoogleChart.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                   controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
                   containerId: 'filter-range',
                 options: {
                     filterColumnIndex: 0,
                   ui: {
                        chartType: 'AreaChart',
                        chartOptions: {
                          chartArea: {
                         width: '100%',
                        left: 36,
                       right: 18
          },
          height: 72
        }
      }
    }
  });
                var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'AreaChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
                    options: {
        width: 1800,
      height: 600,
      legend: {
        alignment: 'end',
        position: 'top'
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'in',
        startup: true
      },
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 36,
        left: 36,
        right: 18,
        bottom: 36
      }
    }
  });

                  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
                 dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, chart);
                  dashboard.draw(data);

            },

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you won't be able to use `arrayToDataTable` if you need date time. instead, you'll need to use the data table json constructor, found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam). as for passing the date, you'll need to use the [date string representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)...

Comment: so there is no way to do it with arrayToDataTable ?

Comment: only way is to manually change each row to a date on the client

Comment: i don't understand , but thank you anyway i will try your first comment :)

Comment: heeelp meee i can't do it alone :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to create date time values,
you will need to manually change each row in the data.

instead of using `arrayToDataTable`...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
```

create a blank data table,
then use the column headings in the data to create the columns,
and the rest to create the rows...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
r.d.forEach(function (row, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    data.addColumn('date', row[0]);
    data.addColumn('number', row[1]);
  } else {
    data.addRow([new Date(row[0]), row[1]]);
  }
});
```

Comment: WhiteHat thank you so much .. like really you helped me a lot thank youu <3